# List of footnotes

Tags: table-of-contents, footnotes

I was wondering if I'll have the option to add something like `\listoffootnotes` in my document like I can use `\listoffigures` or tables...

Anyone knows how?

Comment: Would you mind clarifying why would you need that? I'm not sure whether LaTeX is able to keep track of footnotes, and since they don't have a title, it would look somewhat weird if they are accumulated in a list. Can you post a mockup how such list could look like, and we can try to work out something.

Comment: Well, this is like a second bibliography. In footnotes I have all links and in bibliography just books/articles. It should look like other lists with page number and so on... Thanks mindcorrosive :)

Comment: Maybe you could use endnotes instead of footnotes? Or make extensive use of the footcite command and then print a normal bibliography at the end. [footcite might be a biblatex thing, rather than bibtex, I can't remember]

Comment: Here is a solution for a very similar problem: http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/40504/10570. It is a general approach so that one can use it for listing almost everything.

Comment: @Holle "Answers" that (for the most part) consist of a link to another tex.sx answer should be comments instead.

Comment: @Holle I converted the answer to a comment to the question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I wouldn't recommend a `\listoffootnotes` command for this — instead, you should define a new command like `\externallink{...}` which then populates a `\listoflinks` command. Then write

```
\footnote{\externallink{{...}}
```

Or something along those lines. Anyway, to create new "List of..." lists, you can use the tocloft package. Here's an example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tocloft,url}
\newlistof{links}{lks}{List of Links}
\newcommand\externallink[1]{%
  \refstepcounter{links}%
  \footnote{\url{#1}}%
  \addcontentsline{lks}{links}{%
    \protect\numberline{\thelinks}%
    \protect\url{#1}}%
}
\begin{document}
\listoflinks
\section{Start}
Google\externallink{gmail.com}
and Yahoo\externallink{mail.yahoo.com}
and Microsoft\externallink{hotmail.com}
all have webmail.
\end{document}
```

[mindcorrosive](#3603)'s answer is also very sensible.

Comment: I think your solution is cleaner, and spares the hassle of an additional bibliography.

Comment: Depends, really, on what the links are, etc. etc. I wouldn't think it out-of-place to have a bibtex database of online references with publishing dates, authors, and so on, in which case a 2nd bibliography would be rather sensible.

Answer (score 1):

From your clarification, this is how I would try to do it:

Use two separate bibliographies, with the help of the [`multibib`](https://ctan.org/pkg/multibib?lang=en) package and give each an appropriate name. Set the first one for the books and articles, and the second one for the URLs (that is, your footnotes). See [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/3587/how-can-i-use-bibtex-to-cite-a-web-page) on info how to cite URLs. You would have to add footnotes as `\footnote{\cite{}}`.

I don't have enough time for testing this right now, but give this a try, and if it doesn't work, I'll try to edit this with an example later.