# What needs to be done to update lablst.sty?

Tags: packages, cross-referencing

This question is related to the question [How to get a list of all the labels in a LaTeX document](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/15101/7764).  According to the author of [lablst.sty](http://www.lehigh.edu/ahk3/afs_link/lablst.sty), you can use `lablst` as a global option to `documentstyle` as `\documentstyle[11pt,lablst]{article}` to produce (a list of) label definitions at the end of the document.

Can this be updated so that it can be used with `documentclass`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can try with this `newlablst.sty` to be called by `\usepackage{newlablst}`:

```
\RequirePackage{atveryend,ltxcmds}
\AtVeryEndDocument{\@lablst}
\def\@lablst{
  \parindent 0pt \parskip 0pt
  \normalsize
  \newwrite \labfile \relax
  \immediate\openout \labfile =\jobname.lab\relax
  {\def\toc{toc}
   \def\@writefile##1##2{\def\temp{##1}%
     \ifx\temp\toc
       \immediate\write\labfile{\unexpanded{##2}}%
     \fi}
   \def\newlabel##1##2{\immediate\write\labfile{\string\newlabel{##1}{##2}}}
   \def\bibcite##1##2{\immediate\write\labfile{\string\bibcite{##1}{##2}}}
   \makeatletter
   \input \jobname.aux }
   \immediate\closeout\labfile
   \def\newlabel##1##2{\par \hbox to \textwidth
     {\hfill\makebox[10em][l]{\ttfamily ##1}\makebox[3.5em][l]{\first 
      ##2}\hspace{1em}Page:\makebox[3em][r]{\second ##2}\hspace{4em}}}
   \ltx@ifpackageloaded{hyperref}
     {\def\first##1##2##3##4{##1}\def\second##1##2##3##4{##2}}
     {\def\first##1##2{##1}\def\second##1##2{##2}}
   \def\bibcite##1##2{\par\makebox[2in][l]{\ttfamily ##1}[##2]\par}
   \input \jobname.lab
   \clearpage
}
```

## EDIT

This is perhaps a more robust version; it's just the more modern `lablst.tex`:

```
\RequirePackage{atveryend,ltxcmds}
\def\@lablst{%
  \ltx@ifpackageloaded{hyperref}
    {\long\def\x@firstoftwo##1##2##3##4{##1}%
     \long\def\x@secondoftwo##1##2##3##4{##2}}
    {\long\def\x@firstoftwo##1##2{##1}%
     \long\def\x@secondoftwo##1##2{##2}}
  \let \@mlabel \@gobbletwo
  % No protection needed:
  % 
  \let \protect \relax
  % Better formatting?:
  % 
  \let \raggedright  \relax
  % Only write out toc entries:
  % 
  \def \@writefile ##1##2{%
    \def\lablst@tempa{##1}%
    \def\lablst@tempb{toc}%
    \ifx \lablst@tempa\lablst@tempb
      \par{##2}\par\nobreak
      \vspace{3pt}%
    \fi
  }
  % Allow characters like ^ _ to be printed `verbatim'.
  %
  \def\@lablstverb##1{%
    \def\lablst@tempa{##1}%
    {\ttfamily\expandafter\strip@prefix\meaning\lablst@tempa}}%
  % For first run:
  % 
  \def \newlabel ##1##2{%
    \par
    \hbox to \textwidth{%
      \hfill\makebox[10em][r]{\@lablstverb{##1}}%
      \hspace{1em}\makebox[4.5em][l]{\x@firstoftwo ##2}%
      Page:
      \makebox[2.5em][r]{\x@secondoftwo ##2}%
      \hspace{4em}}\par
  }
  \let \bibcite \@gobbletwo
  {\Large \sl Logical labels within sections}
  \input{\jobname.aux}
  % For second run:
  % 
  \def \bibcite ##1##2{\par
    \hbox to \textwidth{%
    \hfill\makebox[2in][r]{\@lablstverb{##1}}\hspace{1em}[##2]\hspace{4em}}}
  \let \newlabel \@gobbletwo
  \let \@writefile \@gobbletwo
  \par
  \vspace{2\baselineskip}
  {\Large \sl Bibliography logical labels} 
  \input{\jobname.aux}\clearpage
}
```

This seems to works also with **hyperref**.

Comment: This is great!  This should be another (better) answer to (http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/15101/7764).

Comment: I don't know how robust it is; things have changed from 1985 and something appearing in the `.aux` file might break this hack.

Comment: I added a bibliography with one `\bibitem` to my `test.tex` in my answer to (tex.stackexchange.com/q/15101/7764) to further test `newlablst.sty`.  It produced the following LaTeX error.  `! LaTeX Error: Something's wrong--perhaps a missing \item.
l.2 ...ction}{\numberline {1}Table of Contents}{1}`  You can see the test.tex at (http://www.text-upload.com/read.php?id=234036&c=8132979).

Comment: Add `\par` at the end of the `\bibcite` line (I did in my edit).

Comment: test.tex file no longer available at text-upload.com.  It is now available at [github](https://gist.github.com/1530605) for you to test egreg's wonderful newlablst.sty.