# List of referenced entities

Tags: cross-referencing

I am trying to make a list of entities I have made in my text.

```
\begin{document}

\section{Bla}
bla bla bla
\section{Model 1 \label{mod:mod_1}}
bla bla bla
\section {Blubb}
blubb blubb blubb
\section {Model 2 \label{mod:mod_2}
blub bla bla

% Here I want a list of Models
\end{document}
```

With \label I can label my entities and call them with \ref, but how do I easily make a table of all labels with the mod: marker?

Thank you!

Comment: Welcome to TeX:SE!

Comment: Try the `\crtlistoflabels` from [`crossreftools`](https://ctan.org/pkg/crossreftools), as mentioned in https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/418302.