# How to cite a URL in LaTeX?

Tags: bibliographies, citing, urls

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I use BibTeX to cite a web page?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/3587/how-can-i-use-bibtex-to-cite-a-web-page)

What is the standard method for citing a URL in LaTeX and having it in the bibliography?

Comment: Duplicate? http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/3587/how-can-i-use-bibtex-to-cite-a-web-page

Comment: Look at package url.

Answer (score 2):

There are several options, depending on which packages you wish to use and what output format you want. But I've always found that [BibTeX: How to cite a website](http://win.ua.ac.be/~nschloe/content/bibtex-how-cite-website) gives a nice overview of some options. I suppose the list is not exhaustive and maybe not entirely up-to-date, yet it sure helps in giving some really good bibliographies with websites.

Comment: The link is dead: [here](https://web.archive.org/web/20170626094459/http://nschloe.blogspot.de/2009/06/bibtex-how-to-cite-website_21.html) is the archived version of the mentioned website