# What to do to switch to biblatex?

Tags: biblatex

Because of the great answers posted around in the site, I'm finally considering to do the switch and move to `biblatex`. So, the question is what do I have to do?

To give the question some focus, assume that I already have a somewhat largish `.bib` file and a bunch of documents using `natbib` for my references. What do I have to change in my existing `.bib` and `.tex` files?

And what about coauthors? Would it be reasonably simple to instruct them how to work with the new documents using `biblatex`? Do they have to install new software/packages as well?

Comment: The manual is unfortunately of the common latex style: beautifully typeset, and incredibly detailed, but of no use to get you up and running quickly.

Comment: If you prefer looking at sample documents, you can find a bunch of them [online](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/biblatex/doc/examples) or on your computer already in the Tex tree at `texmf/doc/latex/biblatex/examples`.

Comment: From the manual: *For a quick start
guide, browse §§ 1.1, 2.1, 2.2, 2.3, 3.1, 3.3, 3.6, 3.7, 3.11.*.  That's *still* almost 90 pages.

Comment: In the past, I have try to Switch from natbib to biblatex. I prefer natbib... Biblatex is very slow if you have a lot of references....

Comment: Since just a few minutes ago, there now is a nice quick summary rundown of how to [transition from natbib to biblatex](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/427970/117274). I thought this might be worth linking here.

Comment: Overleaf has a very simple guide [here](https://www.overleaf.com/learn/latex/Bibliography_management_in_LaTeX). It took me just a couple mins to switch.

Answer (score 324, accepted):

I've made the switch from `natbib` to `biblatex` two years ago, so I should be able to answer this. That said, Seamus, Simon Byrne, and domwass have already made lots of good points.

(For anyone still asking "Why should I use `biblatex`?": See [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/553/what-packages-do-people-load-by-default-in-latex/2974#2974) [shameless plug].)

### LaTeX document

With `natbib`, a model LaTeX document would look as follows:

```
\documentclass{<someclass>}

\usepackage[<options>]{natbib}

\begin{document}

A bare citation command: \citep{<key>}.

A citation command for use in the flow of text: As \citet{<key>} said \dots

\bibliographystyle{<somestyle>}
\bibliography{<mybibfile>}% Selects .bib file AND prints bibliography

\end{document}
```

With `biblatex` and its built-in styles, this changes to:

```
\documentclass{<someclass>}

\usepackage[<language options>]{babel}% Recommended
\usepackage{csquotes}% Recommended

\usepackage[style=<somebiblatexstyle>,<other options>]{biblatex}

% \bibliography{<mybibfile>}% ONLY selects .bib file; syntax for version <= 1.1b
\addbibresource[<options for bib resources>]{<mybibfile>.bib}% Syntax for version >= 1.2

\begin{document}

A bare citation command: \autocite{<key>}.

A citation command for use in the flow of text: As \textcite{<key>} said \dots

\printbibliography[<options for printing>]

\end{document}
```

Note that I used `\autocite` instead of `\parencite` which is the actual counterpart of `natbib`'s `\citep`. `\autocite` is a high-level citation command that will be translated into the low-level bare citation command appropriate for the chosen style - e.g. it will enclose a citation in parentheses in `authoryear` styles, but produce a footnote citation in `authortitle` styles. Even more, it will automatically move trailing punctuation.

For some of the custom (not already built-in) `biblatex` styles, additional preamble adjustments may be advisable - see the example provided by Seamus for `biblatex-apa`.

As Simon Byrne has mentioned: If you don't want to change every instance of `\citep` and `\citet` in every document to its `biblatex` counterpart, use the `natbib=true` compatibility option.

Typically, you'll select one or several local `.bib` files as your bibliographic database; however, `\addbibresource` also allows to load remote resources and other data types (e.g., `ris`).

### .bib file

domwass has already mentioned that changes to your `.bib` files are not mandatory, but you'll miss some of the goodies offered by `biblatex`. When I switched to `biblatex`, I changed my `address` fields to `location` and my `journal` fields to `journaltitle`. I also added `hyphenation` fields in order to be able to switch languages on a per-entry basis in the bibliography.

### Biber

`biblatex` will work for the most part with traditional BibTeX and its 8-bit version `bibtex8`, but I recommend the use of [Biber](http://ctan.org/pkg/biber) (the default backend since `biblatex` v2.0) for the following reasons:

- Full unicode support.
- No capacity issues. (In contrast, when using BibTeX with bibliographies of about one hundred entries, I've run into errors disguised as obscure warnings - see section 2.4.2 of the `biblatex` manual for details.)
- Multiple or subdivided bibliographies will always be processed in a single pass.
- Many `biblatex` features introduced since v1.1 (e.g., advanced name disambiguation, smart crossref data inheritance, configurable sorting schemes, dynamic datasource modification) are "Biber only".

Biber is included in TeXLive and MiKTeX; [latexmk](http://www.phys.psu.edu/~collins/software/latexmk-jcc/) also supports the use of Biber.

Comment: Great answer! You wrote many good answers regarding biblatex. What do you think about writing a blog article about benefits and use of biblatex on our blog, based on your answers?

Comment: @StefanKottwitz Sadly, I won't be able to deliver a German translation of my "Guidelines" before the end of spring. If that's too late for you, I'll return your bounty.

Comment: Could you please explain how to use BibTeX bibliography styles with BibLaTeX?  I cannot find how to use `amsplain`, for example.

Comment: @Alexey Using BibTeX styles with `biblatex` is not possible.

Comment: So, is there any hope of translating BibTeX styles? Not all publishers provide biblatex styles, though I guess you just have to run with the publishers decision on that...

Comment: If you are switching on Debian/Ubuntu: `apt install texlive-bibtex-extra biber`

Comment: What if I use polyglossia rather than babel?

Answer (score 103):

Converting from `natbib` is pretty straightforward: the minimal requirements are in the header:

```
\usepackage[natbib=true]{biblatex}
\bibliography{dotbibfile}
```

and where you want the bibliography:

```
\printbibliography
```

The `natbib` option will automatically create the relevant aliases for the `\citep` and `\citet` commands, so you can use them as before. If your file has previously been compiled using `natbib`, you may need to delete some of the auxiliary files created by LaTeX and BibTeX (`.aux`, `.bbl`, .`blg`) for it to work properly.

Regarding coauthors, the main issue is that everyone uses the same version (as the package is still being developed, some of the options have changed between versions). Some prominent linux distributions can be [quite tardy](http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=biblatex) with their updates.

Comment: I did not know that about biblatex! and that's a good point about deleting the aux files

Comment: I'm afraid I can't agree with the claim that "natbib will truncate the author list of multi-author works only in the text" but not the bibliography. For one, it's not natbib but the settings of the `.bst` file which control whether (and how) truncation occurs. Second, see [this question](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/553/what-packages-do-people-load-by-default-in-latex/2974#2974) for a specific example of how to modify the code of `unsrt.bst` in order to truncate an author list down to `FirstAuthor et al` in the bibliography.

Comment: Whereas natbib will truncate the author list of multi-author works only in the text, biblatex (even in natbib-compatibility mode) will by default truncate in the text AND the bibliography. To emulate natbib's behaviour, one should use the package option `maxbibnames=99`.

Comment: As we're talking about changes: Note that in `biblatex`, `\bibliography` is deprecated, the use of `\addbibresource` (with the `.bib` file extension) instead is recommended (as @lockstep mentioned in his answer). See section 3.5.1 of the [`biblatex` documentation](http://mirror.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/biblatex/doc/biblatex.pdf).

Answer (score 46):

Just to add to what was previously said: Although you do not *need* to change anything in your `.bib` file in order to use `biblatex`, you will have to make some changes if you would like to benefit from some features that `biblatex` provides. For example (this is not meant to be a complete list):

- `publisher` and `location` are list fields: you could still use, for example, `address = {Berlin, New York}` (with `address` being an alias for `location`), but then you cannot make use of the option `maxitems` (`maxitems=1` would still give you “Berlin, New York”); in order to make use of this option, you would have to change to `address = {Berlin and New York}` (or `location` instead of `address`), which would then give “Berlin et al.” with `maxitems=1`.
- A similar case are some options regarding the appearance of date specifications: instead of using the fields `year`, `month` and `day`, you should use the `date` field with an ISO formatted date, e.g. `date = {2010}` or `urldate = {2010-08-11}`. Then, `biblatex` can make use of some options like “date=short” etc.
- `biblatex` offers some additional fields that other packages do not provide, e.g. `subtitle`, `titleaddon`, `maintitle` for multi-volume works, `editortype`, and many more.

Comment: It's almost always a mistake to give more than one location for a publisher - to see why most style guides ask for just the first listed location, consider that recent OUP publications list 16 primary locations, and several other publishers list 10+ locations.

Answer (score 31):

Nothing really needs to change in your `.bib` to make the switch. Biber is also optional (but recommended). `biblatex` can still work with a standard LaTeX and BibTeX compile.

`biblatex` should be part of most (relatively up to date) TeX distributions now. (correct me if I'm wrong...). Otherwise, it's a fairly standard package installation from [CTAN](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/biblatex).

To get something close to natbib look into the `authoryear` and `apa` citation/reference styles. (Warning: to get [`biblatex-apa`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/biblatex-apa) working you may need to update your versions of `biblatex` and `biblatex-apa`, so it might be best going with `authoryear` at first...)

As an example, here's the relevant parts of a preamble to a recent paper of mine:

```
%%% Bibliography Packages
%% biblatex-apa dependencies

\usepackage[american]{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}

%% biblatex commands themselves
\usepackage[sorting=nyt,style=apa]{biblatex}
\bibliography{../bigbib}

%% Language sensitive biblatex macros need:
\DeclareLanguageMapping{american}{american-apa}
```

And then where I want my bibliography (at the end...):

```
 \printbibliography
```

You also need to replace `\citep` with `\parencite` and `\citet` with `\textcite`. There might be other similar minor changes, but those are the ones I use... [edit: apparently you don't need to do this, see Simon Byrne's answer]

Comment: *should be part of most TeX distributions* – Sadly, Tetex is still fairly widely used.

Comment: Edited. But then, TeTeX probably doesn't even make my "it's a shame people still use X" list. MS Word, IE4,5,6,7,8...

Comment: Generally, one doesn't need to use the `sorting` option because the selected style will set it to an appropriate (for the style) value. (`apa` is a case in point - it uses `sorting=nyt`.) The main exception of this rule is reproducing the effects of the `unsrt` bst-style: Here, one would use `\usepackage[sorting=none]{biblatex}`. (One wouldn't need to set `style=numeric` because that's the default behaviour of biblatex.)

Comment: I'm sure there was some reason I explicitly setting the sorting style... But I can't remember why. LaTeX preamble junk DNA...

Comment: I you pass the `natbib=true` option to the biblatex package you can even use `\citep` and `\citet`

Comment: As we're talking about changes: Note that in `biblatex`, `\bibliography` is deprecated, the use of `\addbibresource` (with the `.bib` file extension) instead is recommended (as @lockstep mentioned in his answer). See section 3.5.1 of the [`biblatex` documentation](http://mirror.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/biblatex/doc/biblatex.pdf).

Comment: Would also like to add this link re: `\addbibresource`: [biblatex - Is there any advantage to using \addbibresource over \bibliography? - TeX - LaTeX - Stack Exchange](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/21439/is-there-any-advantage-to-using-addbibresource-over-bibliography)

Comment: @CharlesStewart: tetex may still be common (i'm just about to retire the machine with my last instance of it), but it doesn't matter, because biblatex requires etex extensions, and they're not present on the latex of tetex 3.  it's possible to navigate around it, but it's probably "not a good idea"...

Answer (score 20):

This answer is more related to the question “[Biblatex guide?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/64907/biblatex-guide)”, but because of [duplicate] mark on it — with which I strongly disagree :) — I post it here.

Let me introduce a `biblatex`-related document I prepared some time ago. It consists of three parts

http://www.khirevich.com/latex/bibliography/
http://www.khirevich.com/latex/biblatex/
http://www.khirevich.com/latex/footnote_citation/

and contains a detailed example of using `biblatex` for numbered footnote citation scheme. This document can be seen as a practical introductory guide, but also — for experienced users — as an example of the `biblatex` workflow for highly customized bibliography. It includes thorough discussion of all introduced biblatex customizations (including appearance of references in the main text and in the bibliography) as well as an example of the customized numeric-comp `biblatex` style.

Answer (score 10):

I made the switch from natbib to biblatex for my master's thesis. Here's the complete [diff](https://github.com/Tarrasch/exjobb/commit/b4ea5098e8e1d4c64dfbb31c2fa8118c1cff4846).

I also had to do `make clean` and `sudo apt-get install biblatex`.

Comment: Very handy for a beginning to use biblatex! thx (:

Comment: For me it was `apt-get install biber` that got me up and running