# How to make my own reference for some arbitrary weblink

Tags: bibtex, pdf, urls, online

How could I make my own reference (bibtex or other) to some arbitrary weblink like http://www.inf.ed.ac.uk/teaching/courses/anlp/slides/anlp13.pdf
so that it appears under the 'References' of the PDF file generated by LaTeX.

Comment: This looks like a duplicate of: [How can I use BibTeX to cite a web page?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/3587/how-can-i-use-bibtex-to-cite-a-web-page)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For BibTeX you will need to create a `MISC` entry like the one below:

```
@MISC{doe:website,
      AUTHOR = "John Doe",
      TITLE = "the website title",
      MONTH = feb,
      YEAR = 2011,
      NOTE = "\url{http://whereever/file.ext}"
}
```

There are also other keys which can be used. I'm using Zotero, a Firefox Plugin, to collect my references. It produces the following BibTeX entry from e.g. this page:

```
@misc{_bibtex_????,
    title = {bibtex - How to make my own reference for some arbitrary weblink - {TeX} - {LaTeX} - Stack Exchange},
    url = {http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/11818/how-to-make-my-own-reference-for-some-arbitrary-weblink},
    howpublished = {http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/11818/how-to-make-my-own-reference-for-some-arbitrary-weblink}
}
```

However, whether or not and how the URL is displayed depends on your used reference style.

---

If you are using BibLaTeX (note the extra 'La') then you can use the new `ONLINE` type:

```
@ONLINE{Doe:2011:Online,
  author = {Doe, John},
  title = {This is an example},
  month = feb,
  year = 2011,
  url = {http://www.test.org/doe/}
}
```

Comment: For URLs, `note` field is not comfortable to use. It's better to use another bibstyle or `biblatex`. And I was told not to cite a web page (no author, no date) directly, but put it in a footnote. I'm not sure if it is a good manner to create such a `misc` entry.

Comment: @Leo: I agree. I simply answered on the technical aspect of the question. Like you said BibLaTeX is much better here. In this specific case I would assume he uses the author and date of the linked presentation.

Answer (score 0):

```
% \usepackage{hyperref}
\href{http://www.inf.ed.ac.uk/teaching/courses/anlp/slides/anlp13.pdf}{This paper}
```

---

I had not realized that you didn't know there's a `url` field in many bibstyles. The four basic bibstyles (`plain`, `unsrt`, `abbrev`, `alpha`) are too old for URLs. More modern styles, like the ones provided by `natbib`(`plainnat`, `unsrtnat`, `alphanat`), and many others (e.g. `ieeetrans` and the ones created by `custum-bib`), provide a `url` BibTeX field.

Comment: I think the OP wants to create a BibTeX entry for this link, not actually embed the hyperlink to it.

Comment: Yes, I want to create a BibTex entry for the link, not a hyperlink.

Comment: Then it is better to use another bibstyle, e.g. `plainnat.bst` or any one supports `natbib`. There is a `URL` field for the url link.