# How do I cite an online book?

Tags: citing, online

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I use BibTeX to cite a web page?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/3587/how-can-i-use-bibtex-to-cite-a-web-page)

I want to cite this book: http://www.sce.carleton.ca/faculty/chinneck/po.html

Here's the citation I was given as an example:

```
@Book{knuth:84,
  author =   {Donald E. Knuth},
  title =    {The {\TeX} Book},
  publisher =    {Addison-Wesley},
  year =     {1984},
  edition =      {15th}
}
```

There is no publisher, no year, no edition etc.

Should I do it like this ( [How can I use BibTeX to cite a web page?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/3587/how-can-i-use-bibtex-to-cite-a-web-page) ) ?

Comment: Surely you want to mention the URI. An access date is useful too, in case the "book" is updated.

Comment: The question linked should cover what you need. The BibTeX `@misc` field is most commonly used.

Comment: This does look like a duplicate: you don't really have an 'online book' as distinct from a webpage.

Answer (score 1):

Depends on the citation style you are asked to use. In my institution (for dissertations) we have to include the uri and the access date.