# Style-independent way in BibTeX to cite a web page as a source

Tags: bibtex, apa-style, mla-style

I know [how to cite a web page in BibTeX](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/3587/17868), but the method proposed is not style-independent.

That is, it suffers from not having metadata for the access date and URL (it's a hack to put the access date and URL into `note` or `howpublished` fields of a `misc` entry type). If I use different styles for a bibliography, or I want to define my own style that needs to be compatible with a publication, my BibTeX entries using this method aren't independent of that style.

For example, look at how the access date appears in the [way to cite websites using APA](http://www.bibme.org/citation-guide/APA/website):

> Smith, J. (2009, January 21). Obama inaugurated as President. *CNN.com*. **Retrieved February 1, 2009,** from http://www.cnn.com/POLITICS/01/21/obama_inaugurated/index.html

Now, look at how the access date appears in the [way to cite websites using MLA](http://www.bibme.org/citation-guide/MLA/website):

> Smith, John. "Obama inaugurated as President." *CNN.com*. Cable News Network, 21 Jan. 2009. Web. **1 Feb. 2009**.

How can I do this without having to modify (hard-code) my .bib entries?

Comment: The problem here is that the 'traditional' styles simply don't know about URLs. Thus the only way is to set up for the appropriate style, or use `@misc` as a fallback. Is [`biblatex`](http://ctan.org/pkg/biblatex) an option for you? If so, you can standardise the information as it deals with URLs 'out of the box'.

Comment: @JosephWright Thanks. biblatex might be an option, although I'm not sure what it entails when 1) using TeXworks and 2) writing papers for conferences/journals that impose their own tex formats.

Comment: TeXworks is  (just) an editor: makes no difference. Journal submission is a different matter, as they set the bibliography style and more importantly `biblatex` is not supported by any journal I know of.

Comment: @JosephWright Thanks again. I only use (tolerate!) LaTeX because of the publications that require it... The path of least resistance is to keep hacking my `@misc` entries.