# Refering to website with bibtex

Tags: bibtex, ieeetran

I am using the latex package from [IEEE](http://ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/IEEEtran/bibtex). I want to know what is the format for referencing a web site? Which fields are required in the reference which contain URL?

Comment: *ieeetran.bst* defines the non-standard entries `@electronic{}`,`@patent{}`,`@periodical{}`, and `@standard{}` and you can use the first one. you can find info on `IEEEtran_bst_HOWTO.pdf` file

Comment: OK. with `@electronic{}`, which fields are required? How can I find the valid fields in the bst file?

Comment: Can [this question](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/3587/how-can-i-use-bibtex-to-cite-a-web-page) help?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Here is the [ieeetran.bst](http://www.math.md/files/download/csjm/2016/IEEEtran.bst)

There are no required fields, and the accepted fields are `author`, `month`, `year`, `title`, `howpublished`, `organization`, `address`, `note` and `url`.

Your actual .bib entry might look something like this:

```
@electronic{website2013,
 author   = "Smith, John",
 title     = "Webpage Title",
 url       = "http://link.com"
}
```

---

Relevant information from the .bst that I referenced to find this out:

```
FUNCTION {electronic}
 { std.status.using.period
  start.entry
  if.url.alt.interword.spacing
  format.authors output
  name.or.dash
  format.date.electronic output
  format.article.title.electronic output
  format.howpublished "howpublished" bibinfo.check output
  format.organization "organization" bibinfo.check output
  format.address "address" bibinfo.check output
  format.note output
  format.url output
  fin.entry
  empty.entry.warn
  if.url.std.interword.spacing
}
```

I also had to reference the definitions for `FUNCTION {format.date.electronic}` and `FUNCTION {format.authors}` to determine that `month`, `year`, and `author` were the proper fields, not `date` and `authors`.

Here is some information about `bibinfo.check` and `bibinfo.warn` (also from the .bst), which is useful for interpreting some of the above code:

```
% bibinfo.check avoids acting on missing fields while bibinfo.warn will
% issue a warning message if a missing field is detected. Prior to calling
% the bibinfo functions, the user should push the field value and then its
% name string, in that order.
```

Comment: With LaTeX on Overleaf.com and the IEEETrans style, I had to use `author="",` rather than `authors=""` in your first example to get the name to appear.

Comment: The link of `ieeetrans.bst` is broken.

Comment: Thank you very much! Is there a website to generate this automatically please?