# BibTeX and "accessed" field for web page

Tags: bibtex

Referring to the question [how to cite web pages](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/3587/how-can-i-use-bibtex-to-cite-a-web-page) what is the best approach if you use Citavi and want to get an "Access date" added?

I got Citavi to add the access date to notes, but I couldn't add an "accessed:" pre-string.

How can I, fit my needs and
a) add the access date straight after the author (in braces)
**Deutsche Börse AG (07.01.2002): Deutsche Börse - Die verschiedenen Indizes, http://www.exchange.de/fwb.indices.html.**
or if this is to tough
b) add an accessed string via citavi or latex?
**Deutsche Börse AG. 2002. Deutsche Börse - Die verschiedenen Indizes, http://www.exchange.de/fwb.indices.html. Accessed 07.01.2002**

I use [this LaTeX-Template](http://www.om.wi.tum.de/fileadmin/w00bdm/www/LaTeX_Vorlagen_Studienarbeiten.zip) which uses [this *.bst file](http://www.iro.umontreal.ca/~lecuyer/tex/latex/macros/ormsv080.bst) for transforming bibtex.

Maybe just adding something to the *.bst file is the easiest option?

---

**Edit:** Following @Micos recommendation I add the corresponding *.bib entry:

```
@misc{OMG.2014,
 author = {OMG},
 year = {2014},
 title = {{About the Object Management Group}},
 url = {http://www.omg.org/gettingstarted/gettingstartedindex.htm},
 keywords = {technology standards consortium;technology standards;MDA;UML;CORBA;Unicode;ISO PAS;ITU-T;Heathcare;Legal;Life Sciences Research;Government;Finance;C4I;Robotics;technical meetings;tutorials;specifications;computer technology},
 note = {05.10.2014}
}
```

Comment: It would be helpful if you showed the complete bib entry that gives rise to the two forms of the typeset entries shown in your posting?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like the bibliography style file `ormsv080.bst` was created with the [makebst](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/custom-bib/) utility. As such, it is unfortunately not programmed to recognize -- and will therefore ignore -- a `field` named, say, `last-accessed-date` or `access-date`.

If you want to stick with this particular bibliography style, you'll need to change the field

```
note = {05.10.2014}
```

to

```
note = {Accessed on 05.10.2014}
```

I'm afraid it's not a good idea to edit the `bst` file itself to prefix "Accessed on " to the contents of the `note` field, as the `note` field can contain just about any kind of information, not just the date a given entry was last accessed on.  The good news is that you'll need to make this edit only once (assuming you don't access this site repeatedly, of course).

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@misc{OMG.2014,
 author = {OMG},
 year = {2014},
 title = {{About the Object Management Group}},
 url = {http://www.omg.org/gettingstarted/gettingstartedindex.htm},
 keywords = {technology standards consortium;technology standards;MDA;UML;CORBA;Unicode;ISO PAS;ITU-T;Heathcare;Legal;Life Sciences Research;Government;Finance;C4I;Robotics;technical meetings;tutorials;specifications;computer technology},
 note = {Accessed on 05.10.2014}
}
\end{filecontents*}
\bibliographystyle{ormsv080}
\usepackage{natbib,url}
\begin{document}
As argued by \cite{OMG.2014}, \dots
\bibliography{\jobname}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Hm .. I see. Thats what I expected :( Thanks for your recommendation. I thought manipulating a *.bst file is an option.

Comment: @lony - "Manipulating a bst file" means (a) creating new `field` types and (b) modifying the many functions that format the entries to recognize and typeset the contents of these fields. Moreover, if and when you switch to a different .bst file -- say, because a journal requires you to use their house style file -- you'd either have to start over with the new bst file or (if you're not allowed to modify the style file...) go back and edit the contents of the `note` field after all. In short, modifying the contents of the `note` fields suitably is less work both the short and long run.

Answer (score 2):

You can skip `filecontents` using the following format

```
@misc{ABC,
 title = {{ABCD} My name is John Doe},
  howpublished = {\url{https://www.google.com}}, 
  year   = "2019 (accessed July 1, 2019)"
  }
```

Comment: Nice solution for styles like ieeetr, however, but it doesn't work for apalike and other styles that use the year in the reference :(