# Timestamp, misc, and date accessed for Bibtex

Tags: bibliographies, bibtex, citing, url

This question has been addressed in parts in many other places ([BibTeX and "accessed" field for web page](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/204660/bibtex-and-accessed-field-for-web-page))
([URL date access missing](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/404227/url-date-access-missing))
but I could not find a satisfactory answer.

I use JabRef to create my bibtex file (it does not matter though, I think). I have hundreds of @misc entries pointing to a website where there is no "url-date" field but there is a timestamp field. I want the timestamp field to be reflected as the date accessed in my main .tex file. How do I do that with minimum manual effort? I do not want to use the manual "Note, Online, date accessed = XXX" idea.

I am using BibTex and pdflatex.

Example:

```
@Misc{AustraliaPost2018,
  author      = {{Australia Post}},
  title       = {Fast facts about {Australia Post}},
  year        = {2018},
  institution = {Australia Post},
  timestamp   = {2020-05-25},
  url         = {https://auspost.com.au/about-us/news-media/fast-facts-about-australia-post},
}
```

Comment: Which bibliography style do you employ at present? Do you have `timestamp` fields just in the entries of type `@misc`, or in other entry types as well? Are there entries with both `timestamp` and `url-date` (or `urldate`?) fields? If the answer is yes, should the contents of both fields be typeset, and in which sequence?

Comment: @Mico I am using plain, ieeetr, vancouver - I can use any. Yes timestamp is only in misc. I do not have url-date in any of the fields. I want the timestamp to automatically map to the url-date if needed. Any consistent sequence is fine as long as my effort is minimum - there are hundreds of these. (Aside on JabRef I do not see the "online" field - all my entries are "misc")