# Bibliography - Many different input options for "date" and "year": How to use in a correct way?

Tags: biblatex, biber

**Let's take a look at one classical bibliography-entry for a online-source:**

(I removed the irrelevant options for better visibility...)

```
@online{ID,
    ALTauthor = {author},
    title = {title},
    date = {date},           % the date of time the document was created (type in this way: 2015)
    OPTdate = {date},        % what is that?
    OPTmonth = {month},      % what is that?
    OPTyear = {year},        % what is that?
    OPTurldate = {urldate},  % the date of time the URL was visited (type in this way: 2015-07-16)
}
```

---

Which option do I have to use for which purpose? I am using Biblatex and Biber.

Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: BibTeX is flexible on fields: the various `OPT...` ones are non-standard so will be ignored by most styles. Have these come from a specific  source, perhaps with a matching `.bst` file?

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I don't think that they come from a specific source - it should be the standard in BibLaTeX I think?

Comment: No, the standard fields for `biblatex` are just `date`, `year`, `month`, _etc._

Comment: Okay, I didn't know that. But which fields should I use now when using Biber and BibLaTeX?

Comment: I think `OPT` is sort of comment in a template to indicate the corresponding field is optional.

Comment: Related: [How can I use BibTeX to cite a web page?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/3587), [Wikipedia: Cite This Page for LaTeX](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Special:CiteThisPage&page=LaTeX&id=413720397). [Biblatex section 2.1.1](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/exptl/biblatex/doc/biblatex.pdf) indicates that all its types support a `url` field, and there's an `online` type for online-only resources that uses author or editor, year or date, title, and url.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using Biblatex and Biber - not BibTeX - then

- `date` is the main date the resource was created in `YYYY-MM-DD` format;
- `year`, `month` and `day` are alternative formats for `date`, provided for backwards compatibility;
- `urldate` is the date you visited the web page in `YYYY-MM-DD` format.

That's it.

For other sources, there is also

- `origdate` which may be used by some styles for an original date of publication. For example, a translated work might use this for the date the original was published, since `date` would be the date of publication of the translation.