# Use BibTeX to cite a website

Tags: bibtex, bibliographies

I looked on this page 
[How can I use BibTeX to cite a web page?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/3587/how-can-i-use-bibtex-to-cite-a-web-)
I used

```
@misc{keyword,
    title     = "Title",
    howpublished        = "\url{link}",
}
```

and the results is

```
Title.         URL.
```

on the same row but I'd like to use a style like this:

```
Title article
URL
```

without dots at the end of the title or URL and a new line for URL. Can I do this?

Comment: Your question is tagged [tag:biblatex], but the title says BibTeX.  Which one do you use?

Comment: BibTeX. Sorry I didn't notice that. I'll edit the tag

Comment: Then you will have to edit the bibliography style.  Which one are you using?

Comment: `\bibliographystyle{unsrt}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## BibTeX

1. Copy the `unsrt.bst` style file to your document's directory and rename to, say, `unsrt-custom.bst`.  On GNU/Linux this can be achieved with

   ```
   cp $(kpsewhich unsrt.bst) ./unsrt-custom.bst
   ```
2. Edit the `unsrt-custom.bst` file.  Add the function

   ```
   FUNCTION {output.newline}
   { duplicate$ empty$
       'pop$
       'output.nonnull
     if$
     "\newline " write$
   }
   ```

   and adjust the `FUNCTION {misc}` accordingly

   ```
   FUNCTION {misc}
   { output.bibitem
     format.authors output
     title howpublished new.block.checkb
     format.title output
     howpublished new.block.checka
     howpublished output.newline % <-- changed
     format.date output
     new.block
     note output
     fin.entry
     empty.misc.check
   }
   ```
3. Run the chain `pdflatex` → `bibtex` → `pdflatex` → `pdflatex` on the following sample document.

   ```
   \begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
   @misc{keyword,
     title = "Title",
     howpublished = "\url{link}",
   }
   \end{filecontents*}
   \documentclass{article}
   \usepackage{url}
   \begin{document}

   \cite{keyword}

   \bibliographystyle{unsrt-custom}
   \bibliography{\jobname}
   \end{document}
   ```
4. Enjoy the output.

[image]

## BibLaTeX

`biblatex` comes with “batteries included” in the sense, that you can control the appearance of the style directly from the document.  To achieve your desired style we modify the representation of the `url` field

```
\DeclareFieldFormat[online]{url}{\newline\url{#1}}
```

where we have used the new `@online` entry type, which is best suited to cite online sources.  The full example boils down to the below document and the following chain of commands: `pdflatex` → `biber` → `pdflatex` → `pdflatex`

```
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@online{keyword,
  title = "Title",
  url = "link"
}
\end{filecontents*}
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[sorting=none]{biblatex}
\DeclareFieldFormat[online]{url}{\newline\url{#1}}
\addbibresource{\jobname}
\begin{document}

\cite{keyword}

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: What if I change in BibLaTex? Would be easier? I'm using TeXStudio on Windows.

Comment: @Shika93 See updated answer.

Comment: I'm using the first solution. Is there a way to set the width of urls? I have a long url that at the end of the line draws a large black space when goes in a new line. Is like `http:\\urlurlurlurl.com\path\path\path\path\**blackblackblack**\path`
I hope you get it. I'll update the question with a screenshot if needed

Comment: @Shika93This question solves the problem: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/3033 The solution is to add the `hyphens` option to the `url` package as in `\usepackage[hyphens]{url}`.