# Cite a youtube video in master thesis using Latex

Tags: biblatex, bibtex, citing

I've come across to a very explanatory video on youtube regarding a specific topic very related to my master thesis. Am I allowed to cite a youtube video in a master thesis and if so, how is it being done with BibTeX reference?  Thank you.

Comment: You should ask your supervisor about whether or not it is allowed.

Comment: It is probably allowed. You can use the `@misc` entry type (miscellaneous) for such references, or use one of the suggestions on https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/3587/how-can-i-use-bibtex-to-cite-a-web-page.

Comment: Which bibliography style do you employ?

Comment: I do use BibTex

Comment: The question whether or not you are allowed to cite a youtube video in your thesis can only be answered by those who are going to read (and grade) it. The question of whether or not it is in general a good idea/accepted to do so is off-topic here and might be appropriate for https://academia.stackexchange.com/. The question of how it can be done in TeX depends on the bibliography package and style you use (the argument to `\bibliographystyle`). With `biblatex` `@online` might work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Concerning your first question: please ask your supervisor. Users here can only guess what is suitable for references in your field of studies and your masters thesis.

The second question:

```
@misc{Author.year,
 author = {Name, Given-Name},
 year = {2019},
 title = {A tutorial video},
 url = {http://www.youtube.com/xyz},
 urldate = {2019-04-08} %date of last access
}
```

The `@misc` entry for bibtex allows several fields that are relevant for online references (ie: URL and access date). The notation here is for bibtex. This is to be seperated from the actual package you use in your document to create reference from `bibtex` files (ie: `biblatex`, `natbib` or `jurabib`) and their respective bibliography stlyes. As moeve mentions in his*her comment, `biblatex` can also make use of `@online`.

Cf also [How can I use BibTeX to cite a web page?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/3587/how-can-i-use-bibtex-to-cite-a-web-page)

Comment: Note that `url` and `urldate` are not supported by all *`BibTeX` styles* (`.bst`), but they should be supported by all *`biblatex` styles*. (The distinction might be important here, the question is tagged with both tags, but so far the OP has only mentioned BibTeX)

Comment: Thanks for the update. I must admit that I find the explanation still slightly confusing or misleading. It is not really "BibTeX" that decides which fields are valid (and with 'valid' I actually mean: are accepted and shown in the output). That decision is down to the bibliography style (`.bst` file) that is used (not the package, but of course some packages are associated with a certain set of `.bst` files). While there is a common core that most (all?) `.bst` files support, fields like `url` and `urldate` are only supported by some styles. ...

Comment: ... So it is slightly misleading to say that "BibTeX allows" the fields or that the notation is for BibTeX as a whole. (Technically, of course this is valid `.bib` syntax, but the real question is about the output in the document, which is not governed by `.bib` file syntax rules but by the `.bst` files.)