# Using bibtex to cite an online pdf file

Tags: bibtex

I did

```
@misc{fundament,
  title = {Foundations for Category Theory},
  author = {Daniel Murfet}
  note  =  {\url{http://therisingsea.org/notes/FoundationsForCategoryTheory.pdf}},
  note = {Accessed: 5-3-2019}
}
```

and loaded `hyperref` in my LaTeX file. It gives this

[image: this]

error. I copied the code from here: [How can I use BibTeX to cite a web page?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/3587/how-can-i-use-bibtex-to-cite-a-web-page) so I don't think there are any typos.

Comment: The accepted answer [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/3587/how-can-i-use-bibtex-to-cite-a-web-page)  I think is superior to the accepted answer here since it doesn't overload the note field and instead uses a distinct "howpublished" field

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because you gave no complete [minimal working example with bibliography (MWEB)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4407) I can not test my corrections for you. Please do it yourself and report the result.

You should add the missing comma after `author` and you should change `http://` to `https://` in your used url:

```
@misc{fundament,
  title = {Foundations for Category Theory},
  author = {Daniel Murfet},
  note  =  {\url{https://therisingsea.org/notes/FoundationsForCategoryTheory.pdf}},
  note = {Accessed: 5-3-2019},
}
```

The missing comma results in the error message you got.

Comment: Ugh, facepalm. The comma fixed it, thank you.

Comment: I'm getting a warning -> ignoring extra "note" field

Comment: using `howpublished` or `url` is probably a better idea than using note twice.