# What should I write in these fields if I want to cite?

Tags: tables, beamer, bibliographies, bibtex

I come across a pdf file and I want to cite it, what to write in these fields if I want to cite it?

```
@misc{ ,
    author = "{}",
    title = "{}",
    year = "",
    howpublished = "\url{}",
    note = "[]"
  }
```

Comment: In taht file appears the author name, title name, the year and another information in the frame at the beggining of the document. Do you use `bibtex`, `biblatex` or another bibliography manager?

Comment: Yes, I use `bibtex`, the one I posted is `bibtex`.

Comment: Ok, I see the author name, but what about the name of the university next to it ? Should I include it in the `author` field ?

Comment: Maybe you can foind another Entry type (instead `misc`) that works with `institution` field.

Comment: Here you can see Entry types and fields ... https://ctan.dcc.uchile.cl/biblio/bibtex/base/btxdoc.pdf

Comment: I can't seems to find a suitable Entry types for these fields.

Comment: Well `misc` looks like the option in this case. With university name you can try with `institution` or `organization`. Maybe this could help you https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/485160/14423

Comment: I don't think that you need to give the author's affiliation in this case at all. Author affiliations are generally not listed in the bibliography. It may be listed if it is in addition the 'publisher' of the work you cite (e.g. as a working paper series, a press release etc.), in which case you need to check which field your style supports for that job (note that there is quite a big variation amongst BibTeX styles in that regard, so `btxdoc` is a good first approximation, but not a guarantee that the field is supported, you have to play around with your style).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A compilable example is as follows.
Here is `a.tex`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{url}
\begin{document}
Perelman~\cite{Perelman2003}.
\bibliographystyle{unsrt}
\bibliography{a}
\end{document}
```

Here is `a.bib`

```
@misc{Perelman2003,
  author =       "Perelman, Grisha",
  title =        "Finite extinction time for the solutions to the
                  Ricci flow on certain three-manifolds",
  year =         2003,
  howpublished = "\url{https://arxiv.org/abs/math/0307245}",
  note =         "arXiv:math.DG/0307245",
}
```

[image]