# Citing a website - reference is spaced out

Tags: biblatex

I am trying to cite a website for my Bachelor Thesis:

```
@misc{ECB,
 author = {ECB},
 year = {2020},    
 title = {Open Market Operations},
 howpublished = {{Retrieved from www.ecb.europa.eu/mopo/implement/omo/html/index.en.html}},
 note = {Accessed on 5 April, 2020},
}
```

[image: This is how the bibliography looks like]

Why is it spaced out so much? Tried several different ways of citing it but it always looks weird compared to normal citations... Any ideas?

Comment: It is spaced out because it thinks the URL is one long word and it does not know where to break it.  https://www.ctan.org/pkg/url might help...

Comment: Also I think [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/3587/15036) has some useful answers.

Comment: @Thruston oh thanks! Ive looked through other threads but did not get it with the \url command. Figured out my document was missing the package - I am still a latex noob and got a template from my Prof :D thx

Comment: You should use the `\@online` entry type rather than `\@misc` and the `url`  + `urldate` fields.

Comment: **If** you are using `biblatex` as your tagging suggests, it would be better not to give the URL in the `howpublished` field and access date in the `note` field. Instead you would give the URL in the `url` field and the access date in the `urldate` field: `url = {http://www.ecb.europa.eu/mopo/implement/omo/html/index.en.html}, urldate = {2020-04-05},`

Comment: If your are not using `biblatex` the best course of action depends on your bibliography style (strictly speaking that is also true with `biblatex`, but since all common `biblatex` styles support `url` and `urldate` it's not relevant here). Some newer styles support a `url` field, but with some older styles the only choice is `howpublished`. In case your style only supports `hopwublished` something like `howpublished = {Retrieved from \url{http://www.ecb.europa.eu/mopo/implement/omo/html/index.en.html}},` helps typeset the URL correctly (load `\usepackage{url}` or `\usepackage{hyperref}`).