# Why doesn't this cite with an URL appear in my citations?

Tags: bibtex, citing, texmaker

I'm writing my master thesis and besides scientific articles I want to cite one URL from the web. However, when I attempt to do that, my latex compiles all the cite sources besides the one that has an url.

I followed this tutorial: [https://engineering.purdue.edu/~mark/puthesis/faq/cite-url/](https://engineering.purdue.edu/%7Emark/puthesis/faq/cite-url/)

However, no luck, the text above that is in my "Cite.bib" file doesn't get shown, only other cites.

```
@misc{Senn:2009,
      title  = "Using {\LaTeX} for Your Thesis",
      author = "Mark Senn",
      url    = "http://engineering.purdue.edu/~mark/puthesis",
      year   = "2009 (accessed February 3, 2014)"
    }
```

Also, I tried the top comment from this example but it doesn't work, everything compiles and nothing happens...

[How can I use BibTeX to cite a web page?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/3587/how-can-i-use-bibtex-to-cite-a-web-page)

Comment: Did you make sure you cite the entry in your document (or use `\nocite{}`)? Did you run LaTeX, BibTeX, LaTeX, LaTeX after you added the entry to the `.bib` file and cited it? It is possible that your bibliography style does not fully support online references (not all styles know the `url` field for example), but that should not stop the entry from appearing in the bibliography at all. In any case you have a much better chance of getting a good answer quickly if you can tell us more about your bibliography setup in the form of a short example document (https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228)

Comment: EWhich bibliography style do you employ? Do you employ a citation management package, e.g., `cite` or `natbib`?

Comment: @moewe I didn't cite it in the document, I just want that is generally listed in the citing part. I use \bibliographystyle{plainnat}

Comment: It works now when I cite in the document, but I want it to work without citing... This is the example that is working: @misc{WinNT,
  title = {{MS Windows NT} Kernel Description},
  howpublished = {\url{http://web.archive.org/web/20080207010024/http://www.808multimedia.com/winnt/kernel.htm}},
  note = {Accessed: 2010-09-30}
}

Comment: If you don't want to cite the entry, use `\nocite`: `\nocite{Senn:2009}` adds the entry to the bibliography, but does not cite it. If you want to add all entries in your `.bib` file to the bibliography without actually citing them, use `\nocite{*}` instead. By default BibTeX only adds cited entries to the bibliography.