# How to create BibTex entrys for web pages automatically?

Tags: biblatex, bibtex, online

Is there an automated way to collect meta data and other information from a webpage and turn them into a BibTeX / BibLaTeX / Biber database entry?

At the moment I manually copy URL, date, title etc. into @online (not @misc)
as recommended [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/3587/how-can-i-use-bibtex-to-cite-a-web-page).

The best case is a functionality similar to Wikipedia's "[Cite this page](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Special:CiteThisPage&page=Phrases_from_The_Hitchhiker%27s_Guide_to_the_Galaxy&id=1060964123&wpFormIdentifier=titleform)", but for an arbitrary page.