# Year not showing up in bibliography

Tags: bibliographies, bibtex

I want to cite as defined in [this link](https://scholar.googleusercontent.com/scholar.bib?q=info:Dc4TsdphbDAJ:scholar.google.com/&output=citation&scisdr=CgXVAtz4EKvQ1FbfwQk:AAGBfm0AAAAAYsXZ2Qlve7CXmZou9ZlKTEcrj3ruLDlQ&scisig=AAGBfm0AAAAAYsXZ2ZS9MeKn6laAeXBP-bpFMGrpOVon&scisf=4&ct=citation&cd=-1&hl=es). However, if I paste in my bib file what the kink contains,

```
@article{planning2010concept,
  title={Concept of Operations for the Next Generation Air Transportation System, Ver. 3.2},
  author={Planning, Joint and others},
  journal={http://ntrs. nasa. gov/archive/nasa/casi. ntrs. nasa. gov/20110008502\_2011007120. pdf},
  year={2010}
}
```

Then, the year does not appear after journal, as can be seen in the attached figure.

[image: output of the bibliography]

I am also attaching a .bib screenshot of how my bibliography looks

[image: my bibliography]

Comment: Note: for internet sources, you really shouldn't abuse the `@article` like that. Use `@misc`. See https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/3587/how-can-i-use-bibtex-to-cite-a-web-page The use of the `journal` and `author` fields are both semantically incorrect.

Comment: That said, for trouble shooting you need to show us what `\bibliographystyle` you are using at least. If I just copy the `.bib` entry from your question into an empty file, and cite it in an `article` with `\bibliogaphystyle{unsrt}`, the year shows up just fine. So the problem (whatever it is) resides with information that you have withheld from us.

Comment: @WillieWong Thanks, now the date appears but the link does not, can you help me with that too? About journal and author, I can change the fields. And I have no idea about the bibliograpy style, I must be using the default

Comment: (a) if you tried something and it didn't work, and you want to ask a follow up, please be **precise** about what you tried. (Show the code.) (b) I would suggest reading up a little bit on some `bibtex` guides (e.g. https://www.economics.utoronto.ca/osborne/latex/BIBTEX.HTM) so that when we try to troubleshoot, the questions we ask you make sense (c) Please update your question with the current status, so other users of this site can more quickly find what the current deal is without having to look through the comments. Thanks!

Comment: Neither the `author` nor the `url` fields look correct. The `author` field should almost certainly be `author={{Joint Planning and Development Office}}`-- a "corporate" author. Why are there lots of spaces in the URL string?