# How to override ordering when citing webpage with a company as the author

Tags: natbib

I am citing several webpages that don't have a human author with the following format as suggested in [this post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/3608/292270):

```
@online{WinNT,
  author = {MultiMedia LLC},
  title = {{MS Windows NT} Kernel Description},
  year = 1999,
  url = {http://web.archive.org/web/20080207010024/http://www.808multimedia.com/winnt/kernel.htm},
  urldate = {2010-09-30}
}
```

Since there was no human author, I added the name of the organization that published the page as the author (`MultiMedia LLC` above). However, in the references section it appears to order this reference by the word `Inc` as though "Inc" is the author's last name, or if a comma is used (`MultiMedia, LLC`), the entry is ordered correctly but the author appears as "LLC MultiMedia". I want it to appear as "MultiMedia LLC" or "MultiMedia, LLC" *and* be ordered by the full string, not "LLC".

How can I get this to work right and not disturb the way other papers in my references list with normal authors are sorted and displayed? Is there a way to tell overleaf to sort and show a particular author on the name I give as it is written in my bib file?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE.

Comment: When dealing with a "corporate author", you need to encase the entire field in an extra pair of curly braces: `author = {{MultiMedia LLC}},`.

Comment: ah perfect, thank you!